# vector layer popup data from database

Tags: openlayers-2, php

I have added vector layer(features) on the map.
when i click on the feature , in the back end it has to take the latlon values and retrieve the data from database(using php) and display the values in the popup.
i am able to retrieve the values from the database, but the values are displaying in another page but not in the popup my code is

```
function createPopup(feature) {

    var temp=temponclick(feature.geometry.x ,feature.geometry.y,name);
            popup1 = new GeoExt.Popup({
        title: 'My Popup',
        location: feature,
        width:200,

        html: temp,
        maximizable: true,
        collapsible: true,
        anchorPosition: "auto"
    });

    popup1.on({
        close: function() {
            if(OpenLayers.Util.indexOf(vectorLayer.selectedFeatures,
                                       this.feature) > -1) {
                selectCtrl.unselect(this.feature);
            }
        }
    });
    popup1.show();
}

vectorLayer.events.on({
    featureselected: function(e) {

        createPopup(e.feature);

    }
});

  mapPanel.map.addControl(selectCtrl);
  selectCtrl.activate();

 function temponclick(x, y,name) {

     var url = 'temperature.php?';
 var query = 'x=' + x + '&y=' + y+ '&name=' + name;

 window.location = url + query;
}
```

temperature.php

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
echo '<input type="label" id="temp"  value="' . $row['temperature'] . '"  />';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your temponclick function has to return the html value sent from the temperature.php not redirect to it. what I suggest is to do an AJAX Call to the temperature.php from your function temponclick(..) with a POST method and then return the data retrieved from it here is an example of it:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'temperature.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            x: x,
            y: y,
            name: name
        },
        success:function(response){
            console.log("data retrieved");
            temp=response;
        }
    });
```

this should be added in your temponclick function after that, you return the temp value:

```
   return temp;
```